# Rails Activerecord adding columns to multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I need to make a migration where a column is added to three separate tables. The views column is an integer and needs to also default => 0. How can I add these columns with activerecord commands? I am using postgreSQL database.

Here is how my migration should look like:

```
class AddViewsToRestaurantsMenusDishes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
   def change
     add_column Restaurant, :views, :integer, :default => 0
     add_column Menu, :views, :integer, :default => 0
     add_column Dish, :views, :integer, :default => 0
   end
end
```

Comment: What's unclear about [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method)?

Comment: I can't find where it says how to add columns for multiple tables and how to set default => 0

Comment: Have you tried `add_column :restaurants, :views, :integer, default: 0`? Repeat two times, changing `:restaurants` to `:menus` and `:dishes`?

Comment: I don't know why you're using `Restaurant`, `Menu`, and `Dish`. Nowhere in the guide (that I can see) does the `change` method take a model name as the first argument.

Comment: Its not correct with that command. And I saw somewhere where a migration was using model names as the first argument which also struck me as odd.

Comment: It would help if you would add to your question whatever errors you're getting. "Not correct" is a little hard to work with.

Comment: "add_column :restaurants, :views, :integer, default: 0" makes an empty migration. The correct way is "AddViewsToTeams views:integer". But that doesn't make it look like the example above where the model is the first argument. And adding default:0 after views:integer just makes it another column instead of making the views default => 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207356/discussion-between-jvillian-and-jabba-the-hutt).

Answer (score 3):

> [`add_column(table_name, column_name, type, **options)`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column)

```
class AddViewsToRestaurantsMenusDishes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
   def change
     add_column :restaurants, :views, :integer, default: 0
     add_column :menus, :views, :integer, default: 0
     add_column :dishes, :views, :integer, default: 0
   end
end
```

None of the methods in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements` or `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition` which make up the whole migrations DSL take models as arguments - its all tables all the way.

This assumes that your tables are conventionally named. If you really wanted to do the same thing from a list of model classes you could do:

```
class AddViewsToRestaurantsMenusDishes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
   def change
     [Restaurant, Menu, Dish].each do |model|
       add_column model.table_name, :views, :integer, default: 0
     end
   end
end
```

But for migrations its usually a good idea to KISS. Especially since they are not supposed to stick around for the entire lifetime of your project.